# How can format specifiers cause a buffer overflow?

Tags: c

I have always heard that strings such as "%d:%d:%f" (random example) can cause a buffer overflow, but I never really understood why.

Is it when they are used with scanf input, printf, or both? Why does it happen? I have been told this many times but couldn't find examples online.

Comment: I was given %x:%x:%s butstill can't understand why

Comment: Please don't tag different unrelated languages, only tag the language you're actually program in. Then always remember to show us a [mre] or it's going to be very hard to help you. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean a buffer overflow instead of memory leak?

Comment: What is it *specifically* about the "random example"? Which part(s) of it? Does the "random example" forget to mention `%s` and `%[...]`, which can cause a buffer overflow with `scanf`? Any of them can cause overflow, if you provide the wrong target type.

Comment: @MicroVirus I think I interchanged the terms, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d`,`%d` and `%f` can hardly result in a buffer overflow if used correctly with correct implementations of `scanf` and `printf`.

But with the `%s` specifier you can get very easily a buffer overflow:

```
char string[10];
scanf("%s", string);
```

If the user types more than 9 characters, the `string` array will overflow.

Also with `sprintf` you can easily get a buffer overflow with any format specifier:

```
char string[4];
sprintf(string, "%d", 1234);
```

Here: the `string` array needs to have 5 characters instead of 4.

Comment: `%d` and friends can cause buffer overflow if used with incorrect code :) Such as `char x; scanf("%d", &x);`. Not sure if it counts.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you're right, I slightly changed the wording of the 1st sentence.